# The "install-templates" is not available in Grails 3

Tags: grails

The "grails install-templates" is not available in Grails 3 any more. I was wondering what is the alternative command for this? How can I customize scaffolding templates in Grails 3? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28414162/grails-3-0-0-m1-scaffolding-templates

Answer (score 0):

The command `grails install-templates` should actually work.

According to the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/install-templates.html) it copies the templates of all code generation activities to the application's `src/main/templates/scaffolding` directory.

I have tried it and it works. Be aware that the customised scaffolding will work only for files generated with `grails generate-all` command and not for views which are generated dynamically in with the controller's `scaffold = true` property.